How to gather std::map from all processes using boost::mpi?
I have maps with some integer values in each process in mpi::communicator. How can i merge values from all maps in one?
Tried to use gather function like mpi::gather(comm, &(*values.begin()), 10, &(*result.begin()), 0);, but there should be a pointer to data, and std::map has only iterators, pointing to values.
